# How can I turn off this function name displaying feature in visual studio code?

Tags: c, function, visual-studio-code, ide, editor

Code Pannel:

[image: Code Pannel]

How to avoid the function name displaying over other code?

Feels like a glitch in VS Code. The function name is displayed over the code part, making it confusing to understand where the function starts. How can this feature be removed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try turning off sticky scroll?
View -> appearance and toggle it off.

Also, may be inlay hints fix the problem.
file->preferences->setting-> search for inlay hints

Restart vscode after changing to make sure.

Comment: Yes , it worked. It was caused by sticky scroll. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I was able to assist.